# Is there really an easyJet's five minute connection between London airports?

Tags: easyjet, lgw, ltn

While waiting for my plane at London Luton, I've spotted following flight on Flightradar24:

[image]

Is there really a five minute long connection between London Luton and London Gatwick airport, served by easyJet? Or is this just a first segment of a longer route or possibly an error in Flightradar24?

I think, it would be easier (and most likely -- cheaper for the airline) to serve this route by bus or train (if possible).

Comment: This is more likely to be a "repositioning" flight, where they move an aircraft from one airport to another. This often happens after disruptions, where planes are not where they were initially planned to be.

Comment: EZY9009/U29009 is normally BTS (Belfast) to LTN (Luton), so it's likely some form of repositioning, and not a scheduled flight.

Comment: Thank you, both. Sounds like a good answer. Care to add, so I could accept it and bring you some rep?